# Python- Share Variable Between Function and It's Decorator

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator, python-decorators

(Python 2.7)Since decorators can not share variables with the function they are decorating, how can I make/pass `object_list` to the decorating function? I have a few of functions that will be using `raw_turn_over_mailer()` decorator and I would like to keep `object_list` to the local decorated function if possible.

```
def raw_turn_over_mailer(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def wrapper(requests):
        original_function = function(requests)
        if object_list:
            ....
        return original_function
     return wrapper


@raw_turn_over_mailer
def one(requests):
    object_list = [x for x in requests
            if x.account_type.name == 'AccountType1']
@raw_turn_over_mailer
def two(requests):
    object_list = [x for x in requests
            if x.account_type.name == 'AccountType2']

@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(hour="*", minute="*", day_of_week="*"))
def turn_over_mailer():
    HOURS = 1000
    requests = Request.objects.filter(completed=False, date_due__gte=hours_ahead(0), date_due__lte=hours_ahead(HOURS))
    if requests:
        one(requests)
        two(requests)
```

Comment: Please provide SSCCE ([Short, Self Contained, Correct, Example](http://www.sscce.org/)) code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't actually run this, but I think it would do what you say want, It creates a`wrapper()`function that calls the original (which now just returns an object list) and then post-processes it (but returns nothing itself):

```
from functools import wraps

def raw_turn_over_mailer(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def wrapper(requests):
        object_list = function(requests)  # call original
        if object_list:
            #....
    return wrapper

@raw_turn_over_mailer
def one(requests):
    return [x for x in requests if x.account_type.name == 'AccountType1']

@raw_turn_over_mailer
def two(requests):
    return [x for x in requests if x.account_type.name == 'AccountType2']
```

This seems like a convoluted way to process the results of calling a function. You could just call the post-processing function and pass it the function to call to get the object list.